# display file from url with content type octet-stream inside of a html page

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, pdf

we get PDFs from Azure which have a Content-Type of `application/octet-stream`. I want to embed this PDF inside of a `<iframe>` or `<object>` (or anything else thats capable of doing it) HTML page.

I tried to convert the PDF to a Base64 String, but has too bad performance, because it could be that we got 50+ PDFs on the same page. The PDFs itself are logos, don't ask me why they are PDFs.

Is there any other way i can try? Is it in any way possible to display in an image tag?

We are using Java in our backend, so i could change some settings of the file before delivering it to the frontend.

**EDIT**

as suggested, i tried to set the content-type of the files inside the Azure Container to `application/pdf` like the following:

```
for (BlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
    if (blobItem.getName().split("\\.")[1].equals("pdf")) {
        BlobItemProperties props = blobItem.getProperties();
        props.setContentType("application/pdf");
        blobItem.setProperties(props);
    }
}
```

However, the content-type inside of the Azure Container is not being changed. What do i miss?

Comment: Why not change the content type property of the blob itself to actual content type?

Comment: @GauravMantri do you know if there is a possibility to change the content-type of the files on the Azure platform for a whole container? i got over 4000 pdfs, i cant update them one by one.

Comment: It should be possible via Azure PowerShell Cmdlets (you may have to write some extra code for that) or you can use SDK to do it yourself. The idea is to list the blobs and then set properties of each blob appropriately.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will do it using the Java SDK, i already listed all blobs, and also set the properties, but after that i do have to upload the file again right? If yes, how would i create an InputStream from a blobItem ?

Comment: @GauravMantri any chance that you could help me with that problem? Can i set the content-type of the BlobItems without downloading/uploading all the files? I tried to just set the Properties with `setProperties()` but that didnt seem to update the file on Azure.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written. To set the properties, you don’t need to download and upload the blob.

Comment: @GauravMantri i edited the question with more infos.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. I’m wondering if your code is even going in the if block. Can you please check that?

Comment: yes it is going in the if block and even sets the content-type correctly, it just seems not to update in the azure container itself.

Comment: @GauravMantri my guess is, that i only change the properties on the local object, but the information does not get passed back to the azure container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer to that problem is to just update the files inside the Azure Container to have a content-type of `application/pdf`.

In Java i managed to do this like this:

```
for (BlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
        if (blobItem.getName().split("\\.")[1].equals("pdf")) {
            BlobClient blobClient = container.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
            BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType("application/pdf");
            blobClient.setHttpHeaders(headers);
            LOGGER.info("Updated content-type to application pdf for logo: {}", blobItem.getName());
        }
    }
```